# What's the difference between @Cacheable Method and @Cacheable Class on ehcache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

Working with ehcache I noticed that @Cacheable annotation could be used on top of a class decleration or on top of a method decleration, such as;

Cacheable class:

```
@Cacheable
class CacheableClass{
    Long l;
    Integer i;
    String s;


}
```

Cacheable method:

```
    class ...
            @Cacheable
            public List<ToBeCached> getCacheableClassList()
            {
                    ...
            }
```

If @Cacheable is on top of a class then you cannot give the name of the chache but if you declare on top of a method you can give the name of the cache declared in the configuration xml. I suppose I miss something since using @Cacheable for class declerations seem obsolute to me.

Comment: Which @Cacheable u r using - javax, spring cache or any other third party cache ?

Comment: yeah you are right about the fact that for classes @Cacheable is from hibernate... it is annoyingly confusing. so what about it? still what is the difference?

Answer (score -1):

Using **ehcache-spring-annotations :**

@com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.**Cacheable(cacheName = "test")** if we give this at **type level** then it gives error saying **The annotation @Cacheable is disallowed for this location**.

According to documents I ever read **Annotation Placement :**

1. On a method.
2. On an interface or
3. On a public method on a class

**Spring recommends that you only annotate methods of concrete classes with the @Cacheable annotation, as opposed to annotating methods of interfaces.**

When using proxies, you should apply the @Cacheable annotation only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected, private or package-visible methods with the @Cacheable annotation, no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured cachable settings.

**Using Spring Cache**

If you use **@org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable(value="test")** where value represents the name of the cache. You can specify this at **type &/or method level.**

**You can try this & tell whether you get error  or not :-**

```
@com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable(cacheName = "test")
@org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable(value="")
public class PortalDatabaseAdapterImpl{

    @com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.Cacheable(cacheName="test")
    @org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable(value="test")
    public List<PageControl> getLoginPage() {}
}
```

If you didn't get error then I have to update myself.

Answer (score -2):

Using @Cacheable at method level means, the results of the method are cached.
Using @Cacheable at interface level is used to define custom annotations as below,

//Custom annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Cacheable(value="books", key="#isbn")
public @interface SlowService {
}
```

The below code

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="#isbn")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

can be replaced with

```
@SlowService
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

But I have never seen applying @Cacheable annotation at Class level.

Comment: I am not clear about what the code above (findBook method) does. Does it also fetch from the cache? Let's say the book is cached beforehand and findBook method is called and it should return the book. does it directly returns the book instead of running the method? or is it just cacheing the return value?